# Java websocket client with spnego

Tags: java, websocket, spnego

I need to connect to a websocket service which uses spnego authentication from a stand alone java process.

Can anyone provide a java example or point me at a library that has this functionality please?

I can query a rest api on the same server using SpnegoHttpURLConnection - so the spnego kerberos part works.
I can also connect to the websocket if I disable the authentication on the server.

However SpengoHttpURLConnection doesn't have any easy way to upgrade the connection to a websocket, and I can't find a websocket client library that lets me configure spnego authentication.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/part-vi-http-spnego-authentication.htm#JSSEC-GUID-996F729E-5FEA-4E29-A32A-78FB510B2D80 - and is this helpful in any way?

Comment: Possibly, it doesn't mention websockets but it might work to configure a websocket client lib which is capable of using the jaas config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the SPNEGO token using [Kerb4J](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j) and add it to headers using [ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator.beforeRequest(Map> headers)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#beforeRequest-java.util.Map-) method.

If your websocket is running on `wss://ws.server.com` and you authenticate using `svc_consumer` account and `/opt/myapp/consumer.keytab` keytab the code would be like this:

```java
SpnegoClient spnegoClient = SpnegoClient.loginWithKeyTab("svc_consumer", "/opt/myapp/consumer.keytab");

@Override
public void beforeRequest(Map<String,List<String>> headers) {
    SpnegoContext context = spnegoClient.createContext("https://ws.server.com");
    headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList(context.createTokenAsAuthroizationHeader()));
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [Kerb4J](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j)

Comment: Genius. And thanks for the header config snippet - would have taken me a while to find that.
Unfortunate you can't use your own ClientEndpointConfig with an annotated Endpoint implementation.